# Is there a way to tell if a limit is positive infinity or negative infinity without graphing?

Tags: calculus, limits, differential

If I have such limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2x^2-4x}{x+1}$ to calculate.

How can I know if the result if $-\infty$ or $\infty$ if I don't have a way to graph this function and I don't know how this graph looks like?

Because the direct substitution will be like this:

- $\dfrac{2(-\infty)^2-4(-\infty)}{-\infty+1}$

I am always confused when calculating the limit when it is approaching $-\infty$ because it is not as easy as ones that approach $\infty$

Comment: "*I am always confused when calculating the limit when it is approaching `−∞` because it is not as easy as ones that approach `∞`*" - then just replace every `x` with `-x` and say `x` approaches `∞` (here `(2x² + 4x)/(1 - x)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the numerator and denominator are polynomials, you can simply ignore all but the highest power term in numerator and denominator, as the highest power term in each will dominate the others as $x$ moves far away from $0$. In your case, for instance, the function behaves like $\frac{2x^2}{x}=2x$ when $x\to\pm \infty$.

One can justify this by, for instance, dividing numerator and denominator by the highest power term of the denominator (including the coefficient if there is one), and working with the result. In your case
$$
\frac{2x^2/x-4x/x}{x/x+1/x}=\frac{2x-4}{1+\frac1x}
$$
It should now be easier to see what happens in the limit.

Comment: So since 1/infinty will be zero, so it will be $2(-\infty)-4 = -\infty$?

Comment: @YanZhuang Exactly. If you choose the highest-power term of the denominator to divide, the denominator will always go to $1$, and you can look at just the numerator, where the highest power term will decide.

Comment: Sure thanks I get it! But what about other types of functions such as $x^{-\infty}$ or $ln(-\infty)$?

Comment: You need to read about [indefinite forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)

Comment: Yes I know about indefinite form. But $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} ln(x)$ is not an indefinite form, and how do I solve it if I don't know the graph of $f(x) = ln x$

Comment: @YanZhang There is no general trick that works for everything. Experience is the best help there. Also, how could you not know what the graphs of $\ln x$ or $a^x$ look like?

Comment: @YanZhuang `ln` isn't defined for negative values, so how can you possibly try to get it's limit at minus infinity?

Comment: Also think of $x^{-\infty}$ as $\frac{1}{x^\infty}$ then if for example $|x|>1$ you have $\frac{1}{±\infty}$ -> $0$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:
$$
\frac{2x^2-4x}{x+1}=\frac{x(2x-4)}{x(1+(1/x))}=\frac{2x-4}{1+(1/x)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can divide everything by $x$ to make your expression simpler.

This means that $\frac{2x^2-4x}{x+1} \frac{x}{x}$ this is multiplying by one and will not change your limit.

Now $\frac{\frac{2x^2-4x}{x}}{\frac{x+1}{x}}$ And the denominator is clearly equal to one when $x$ approaches infinity and negative one when $x$ approaches negative infinity. Your numerator simplified to

$2x-4$

Now it’s easy to see the value of your limit.

Tip: In general, plug in a large number (e.g. $10000$), that will give you the limit on tests

Answer (score 0):

You have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2x^2-4x}{x+1}$.

The denominator $2x^2 - 4x$ is domined by $2x^2$ as $x$ becomes larger($\infty$) or smaller($-\infty$), and since the pow of $2x^2$ is even, therefore $2x^2 - 4x \to +\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$

The numerator tends to negative value as $x \to - \infty$.

Therefore the "mixture" of both is an negative sign, therefore the function will have negative sign as $x\to -\infty$.